# How to implement DML operations like insert and delete in a SQL Server Function

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am working in Oracle to SQL Server Migration using SSMA tool. In oracle we have DML operations like insert and delete implemented in a function, when the code is migrated to SQL server these DML operations are not implemented in SQL server.

Do I need install any supporting packages in order to accomplish it?

I googled and did some investigation but couldn't get any better solution. I tried converting this function to procedure it worked but the problem is these procedures cannot be called by any select queries and all

Comment: You just can't do that in a function in SQL server.

Answer (score 2):

In SQL Server you are not allowed to perform Create/Update/Delete operations in functions. If you need, you can create [STORED PROCEDURE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-procedure-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16). But the stored procedure itself, cannot be used in `SELECT` statements (joins, apply). So, if you need to used it results in a `JOIN` for example, you can `INSERT` its results in table, but there are [limitations](https://stackoverflow.com/q/653714/1080354) there, too.